# R Studio dbWriteTable error writing to Hive SQL

Tags: sql, r, dataframe, csv, hive

I'm using R Studio to ingest a csv file and write it to a table in Hive SQL using the following code:

```
library(DBI)
library(readr)

db_connection         <- get_connection()
table_name      <- "dbname.tablename"
csv_file        <- "filelocation/datafile.csv"
table_data      <- read_csv(csv_file)
dbGetQuery(db_connection, paste0("DROP TABLE ",table_name))
dbWriteTable(db_connection,table_name,table_data)
```

However I'm receiving the error:

```
Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 2:8 cannot recognize input near '?' ',' '?' in expression specification 
<SQL> 'INSERT INTO `dbname.tablename` (`col1`, `col2`, `col3`)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)'
```

(I've made things such as db and table name generic names)

It seems dbWriteTable isn't reading the csv file/data frame properly. It's a 3 column csv file and all data are character formats.

Any help would be appreciated!

Code is above and what I expect is that the csv is read into a data frame which is then used to create the table. It's not complicated data but I must be doing something wrong?

Comment: (1) It seems Hive SQL does not want to use `?` as a placeholder for parameter binding. Since you're using `dbWriteTable`, that suggests the maintainer should get involved. It's not clear from this where `get_connection()` is defined (or if that is even important, tbh). What version of Hive SQL are you connecting to? (2) I have a hard time believing `readr` is necessary for this, nor that _that_ CSV "file" is a problem, the [tag:csv] tag is likely a red herring. (2) Side note, `"drop table"` expects no reply, you should be using `dbExecute` instead of `dbGetQuery` (though not an error).

Comment: For #1 above, different DBMS types use different indicators: some use `?`, some use `$1, $2, $3`, some use `:name`. While none of that helps you to fix this exact problem, I say it to inform you that if the backend is misconfigured or not told correctly about the dialect of DBMS (if going through ODBC), there are irreconcilable differences.